# Let exceptions thrown or check in VB.NET (performance-vise)

Tags: vb.net

Let's say we have a

```
Dictionary(Of Date, List(Of SomeClass))
```

And we got ~ a million rows in a database, so I am curious which one is better performance-wise, to check if my Dictionary has key, or adding directly in try catch clause without checking it?

```
While Reader.Read
    Try
        MyDictionary.Add(Reader("SaleDate"), New SomeClass(Reader("SaleData")))
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Silence here
    End Try
End While

While Reader.Read
    Try
        If Not MyDictionary.ContainsKey(Reader("SaleDate")) Then
            MyDictionary.Add(Reader("SaleDate"), New SomeClass(Reader("SaleData")))
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("ERROR")
    End Try
End While
```

Comment: Is the presence of an existing entry in the dictionary an *exceptional* circumstance, which is the result of an error, or is it something that will happen regularly, and for good reasons? Generally, empty `Catch` blocks are the sign of something very wrong.

Comment: If you want to overwrite it if it exists you can simply use this one liner: `MyDictionary(Reader("SaleDate")) = New SomeClass(Reader("SaleData"))` (note that you have declared a `List(Of SomeClass)` but you're assigning a single instance which does not compile).

Answer (score 1):

1. You should not worry about performance until you have a performance issue.
2. You should never catch exception if you do not expect it and have a recovery plan and there is no other way to check and see if there will be an exception.
3. Exceptions are a good thing. There are there to protect you and your application users. So don't abuse them or catch them every where.